# Extraer pesos/weights en ACP/PCA psych::principal

Tags: r

estoy realizando un Análisis de Componentes Principales (ACP) en R para resumir los patrones de correlación mensual encontrados en 30 regiones muestreadas. Para ello, estoy utilizando como input una matriz de 10 (meses) x 30 (regiones) -descargar [aquí](https://ufile.io/1o20z)-.
En un principio estaba trabajando con la función `psych::principal` , pero al introducir la matriz obtengo el siguiente error:

```
pc <- principal(dat,nfactors = 2, residuals = FALSE, rotate="varimax", n.obs=NA, covar=TRUE,scores=TRUE, missing=FALSE, impute="median", oblique.scores=TRUE, method="regression")
```

> Warning messages: 1: In cor.smooth(r) : Matrix was not positive
>   definite, smoothing was done 2: In principal(dat) :   The matrix is
>   not positive semi-definite, scores found from Structure loadings

La función se ejecuta, el problema es que pc$weights es igual que pc$loadings.
Cuando la matriz es cuadrada, o el número de columnas es menor al de las filas se obtienen los weights sin problema, no obstante, no es el caso de mis datos.

La función `principal` , usando los datos de ejemplo de la función, me permite extraer directamente los `loadings`, `scores` y `weights`. Me es importante extraer los `weights` de las componentes principales pues necesito expresar los `scores` en la misma unidad de correlación que la variable de entrada.

He probado la función `stats::prcomp` con mis datos y no me alerta de ningún error, pero no devuelve a simple vista los weights tal cual se definen en `principal`.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda facilitada.
Gracias.

Comment: Hola Mariana. Una pregunta ¿estás pasando a `principal` una matriz de correlaciones? Eso parece viendo los datos (entre 1 y -1), sin embargo no es rectangular. En la llamada estás pasando el argumento `covar=FALSE`, que se usa para dar a la función los datos en crudo y que esta haga primero la matriz de correlación/covarianza y después el PCA. Según `help(principal)` "covar: If false, find the correlation matrix from the raw data or convert to a correlation matrix if given a square matrix as input." Puede ser por ahí el problema.

Comment: Hola @mpaladino , en la pregunta dejé covar=FALSE porque estaba haciendo pruebas cambiando los parámetros. Sigo trabajando con covar = TRUE porque, efectivamente, los datos de entrada son correlaciones [He editado el parámetro en la pregunta]. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Aclaración

Viéndolo con más detenimiento tus datos son correlaciones entre `months`  y `x102 ... x607`, pero **no** son una matriz de correlaciones, que debería ser cuadrada y tener las mismas variables en filas y columnas. Entonces `covar = FALSE` sería lo correcto. En ese caso `principal` calcularía la matriz de correlaciones de las correlaciones de las columnas `x102 ... x607` y hace el PCA sobre esa matriz. ¿Es lo que estás buscando? Independientemente del problema de `weights`

## Coincidencia de `loadings` y `weights` con `principal`

Revisando la (muy poco amigable) documentación de `psych` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/psych.pdf en el apartado `principal` leo que

> The regression weights are found from the inverse of the correlation matrix times the component loadings. [p. 302]

Y viendo el código de la función encuentro esta línea:

```
if (scores && raw) {
    result$weights <- try(solve(r, result$Structure), silent = TRUE)
    if (class(result$weights) == "try-error") {
        warning("The matrix is not positive semi-definite, scores found from Structure loadings")
        result$weights <- result$Structure
    }
```

Que es la que produce el 2do `warning` de tu código y es la única parte del código que produce esa advertencia, así que es seguro que ese es el `if` que se está ejecutando.

¿Qué quiere decir es línea? Que si no puede calcular la inversa de `r` y `Structure`, regresa `Structure` y emite un `warning` muy poco informativo. Por eso en tu caso coinciden pesos y cargas.

> Nota: `solve()` resuelve la inversa de dos matrices.

No estoy completamente seguro, pero creo que deberías tener datos crudos crudos para poder hacer lo que estás buscando. Es decir, no correlaciones en `months` y las otras variables, sino las mediciones directas.

## `prcomp`

De acuerdo con la documentación de esta función `weights` no está dentro del output que produce. Podrías calcularlo haciendo la inversa de la matriz de correlaciones y cargas, pero deberías tener el mismo error que en `principal`.

Lamento que no haya una solución fácil al problema.

PD: también podría ser un bugs en `psych`. Los tiene a montones.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias mpaladino, por el tiempo invertido en realizar las pruebas. Definitivamente no es posible abordar el análisis como pretendía. Pensaré alternativas para reducir dimensionalidad a las variables. De nuevo, muchísimas gracias.